# Force a PCI device to be issued a specific I/O port range

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, pci

I am trying to port a driver to Linux, but the device doesn't respond to commands issued to it's I/O port range under Linux. It responds correctly under windows, which assigns it a different port range.

I suspect a possible issue may be that it is somehow incompatible with I/O port range that Linux kernel assigns to it.

The I/O ports are configured through normal PCI auto-configuration during boot - before driver is loaded - and are reflected in PCI BAR and in `lspci` and `/sys/bus/pci/.../resource*`.

BIOS settings change neither port range nor behavior on either OS.

**Is there any way to force Linux PCI subsystem to assign a specific I/O port range to a specific device?**

Or at least somehow cause a change in assigned port numbers?

*(if you believe there is no way to do that, please specify exactly how you arrived to this conclusion)*

Comment: Hm if that was necessary for the device to work, you couldn't have two of these devices in your system at all. Even worse, if that requirement was normal, then random PCI devices would conflict!

Comment: It may be possible that it was never anticipated that there may be multiple such devices in a single system. Due to the nature of the device (proprietary testing equipment), that scenario is rather unlikely. Furthermore, it may not only work with a single port - just that the port range linux assigns to it somehow triggers a bug in its firmware.

Comment: Ah friggin frickleware. It would still be surprising!

Comment: Not necessarily. But I'd like to confirm or disprove that. It's possible there may be something else I'm not accounting for - at least I'd like to know it is not this.

Comment: Moving the card to another PCI slot fixed my problem as long as the card is in that slot - although I/O port range in Linux is the same, I/O port range in dual-boot Windows now coincides with Linux one, and the card works in Linux (it works in Windows in either slot with either port range). Moving the card to adjacent slot (which I of course tried before asking this) made no difference in either OS but moving to opposite one did. I'm not sure what is happening and will investigate the issue further. However this question still stands.